# Is a compound statement always 1 block?

Tags: java, if-statement

The if compound statement is 1 block.
A compound statement consists of 0 or more statements

Now if you have

```
if (expression) {
    // do something
}
else {
    // do something else
}
```

Is it one compound statement or two?
1 compound statement = 1 block?
Just because the 2 blocks seem to belong together.

Comment: That is a single statement, specifically an [IfThenElseStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-IfThenElseStatement)

Comment: @AndyTurner so you say that a compound statement can consist of more than 1 blocks?

Comment: well sure, because you can always have nested blocks too.

Comment: @AndyTurner is it true for C#, or other languages too?

Comment: I don't agree with @Andy Turner, because of compound statement as a definition is a set of commands in between curly braces, in these case there are two.

Comment: @AlanSereb there is no such thing as "a compound statement" in Java (at least, the JSL doesn't mention or call it that way)

Comment: I don’t understand the reason for asking. This knowledge seems absolutely useless.

Comment: @dyukha I wouldn't say it's useless: I write compiler tools, and this is the sort of thing I often find myself caring about.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I'm pretty sure you don't care whether `ifElseStmt` and `blockStmt` are called compound or not. What matters is their syntax and that they both are statements. You can notice that this whole discussion is about definition. Definition which no one ever use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A compound statement consists of none or more statements enclosed within a set of braces: {}.

Source: https://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Companion/glossary/compound_statement.html)

It means that these are two compound statements because there are two sets of curle braces. The statement above could be represented just like this:

```
if (expression) {
    // do something
}

if (!expression) {
    // do something else
}
```

EDIT:
In java some commands allow you to skip curly braces if there is only a single command to be executed (like `while` or `if`). For example:

```
if (expression) doSomething();
else doSomethingElse();
```

These will count as a double compound statement as well because it is treated by compiler same as the above.

Comment: That is C++ not Java

Comment: @Patrik Nusszer, here is one for you for Java. It's the same concept, however. http://www.cs.ait.ac.th/~on/O/oreilly/java-ent/jnut/ch02_06.htm (2.6.2). I chose that example because of its shortness and ability to quickly grasp the concept. I am very sad, you disregard my answer only because you found c++ in that context. Programming languages share in common many concepts including this one.

Comment: Yes, that is how you turn the else into if by negating the expression. How would you do the same with else if? Statements are said to be executed in order, but in case the if clause is executed the else if clause will not be

Comment: No I do not disregard it. I am happier with the fact that it is a general rule

Comment: @PatrikNusszer, it does not matter. The definition states that the compound statement is anything that goes between curly braces.

Comment: But there are others stating otherwise and I do not know who is right

Comment: @PatrikNusszer your question presumes the existence of a thing called a "compound statement". By the definition of a compound statement as zero or more statements enclosed in braces, you have an if statement containing two compound statements. However, this is what is called a [block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2) in Java; you don't have to use blocks inside an if/else. It is a somewhat tautological interpretation that an if/else statement containing blocks contains blocks.

Comment: @AndyTurner, the article by O'Reilly I provided in the above states otherwise, even though, I completely agree with you that you rearly come across `compound statement` term in Java.

Comment: Hello! I know it is Python, but have a look at this one. It says that a compound statement consists of clauses. A clause consists of the header which checks the given expressions and starts the execution of the suite that belongs to it. So according to it the compound statement includes the if, else if, and else clauses as well: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html

Comment: But actually, that seems to be a very isolated case, because elsewhere, in Microsoft’s C# documentation, when I read about C and C++, when I read about JavaScript regarding this on w3schools I see that if, else, else if are all distinct compound statements. So yes, a compound statement is always a blocks. Thanks for your answer!